# Is the first visually recorded use of anti-cavalry defences on the Bayeux Tapestry?

Tags: cavalry

[image]

The Norman cavalry was feared throughout Northern France before October 1066. Are there any depictions of a working defence against them before Harold II?

Comment: Which question do you want answered? The title asks about visual representation; the body of the question asks about military tactics.  These are two different questions - which interest you?

Comment: Pretty sure the Greeks and Romans had fairly good defence tactics against cavalry... Must have been documented for historians to talk about it...

Comment: see [shield wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shield_wall).

Comment: @HorusKol - Up until the time of the stirrup they did. After that, [not so much](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirrup#Great_Stirrup_Controversy). Perhaps this question is talking post-stirrup?

Comment: Haven't walls and ditches, both of which are effective anti-cavalry defences, been around pretty much since people started building homes?

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestions in the comments, I found these images where infantry seem to be holding their own against cavalry.

[image: infantry against cavalry]
This photo is from https://www.amnh.org/exhibitions/horse/how-we-shaped-horses-how-horses-shaped-us/warfare/riding-into-battles/

There's also this.

[image: Macedonian]

This photo is from http://slideplayer.com/slide/5353886/17/images/6/Asclepiodotus+(5.1):+The+Macedonian+bronze+shield+of+eight+palms%E2%80%99+width+and+not+too+concave+..jpg